# Adding Select Value to jQuery string

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm trying to implement chained selects using this plugin:
http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/chained

```
        <script>
        $( document ).ready(function() {
            $("#code").remoteChained({
                parents : "#type",
                url : "/api/"
            });
        });
    </script>
```

I have this code at the top, however I want to append the value of #type to the api URL. Like:

```
        <script>
        $( document ).ready(function() {
            $("#code").remoteChained({
                parents : "#type",
                url : "/api/".$("#type").val()
            });
        });
    </script>
```

How do I go about this?

Comment: `+` is the string concatenation character you are looking for : `url : "/api/"+$("#type").val()`

Answer (score 0):

The concatenation of strings in javascript is done with `+` not `.`

i.e.:

```
    $( document ).ready(function() {
        $("#code").remoteChained({
            parents : "#type",
            url : "/api/" + $("#type").val()
        })
    });
```

Comment: Yes, as I already commented. No need to answer such questions - now it cannot be deleted.